# How to do a bulk svn mv in Unix

Tags: svn

I want to bulk move a large number of files from one directory to another in svn.  Unfortunately svn only supports moving one file at a time.

Basically I want to move files of a certain type (*.xml) to a completely different directory e.g. mv foo/bar/*.xml forbar/xml

I tried playing around with find and using -exec but I need to strip the directory off for the second argument.  Any ideas?

EDIT: Using bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the `-execdir` option. This runs *from* the directory that the source files are in (which avoids race conditions with directory linking and etc).

```
find -name '*.xml' -execdir svn move {} `pwd`/foobar/{} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using bash:

```
for x in `find -name *.xml`; do
   echo svn move $x forbar/`basename $x`;
done
```

And once you are satisfied that the output is correct, remove the 'echo' from the second line.