# Can SVN mv be optimized to svn copy+delete?

Tags: svn, find, grep, xargs

I have tens of thousands of images within a specific directory. I have hand-picked specific files from this directory that I want to move into a subdirectory:

`>find . -type f -name '*.png'| \
 grep -Ev "(_retina|_hd|_iphone)"`

This results in thousands (instead of tens of thousands) of images, which is what I want. I want to move those images from `./` to `./tmp/`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581546/how-to-do-a-bulk-svn-mv-in-unix) post asks how to move these images within SVN en masse, although it is still using `svn mv`. This moves the images one-by-one, and is very slow:

`>find . -type f -name "*.png"| \
 grep -Ev "(_retina|_hd|_iphone)"| \
 xargs -I CMD svn mv "CMD" "tmp/CMD"`

Since svn preserves file revision history with an `svn cp`, this appears to be faster:

`>find . -type f -name ".png"| \
 grep -Ev "(_retina|_hd|_iphone)"| \
 xargs -I CMD svn cp "CMD" "tmp/CMD"
>find . -type f -name ".png"| \
 grep -Ev "(_retina|_hd|_iphone)"| \
 xargs -I CMD svn rm "CMD"`

I first `svn cp` all the desired images, which seems to fly through very quickly. Then I run `svn rm` to delete the original images, which also goes very fast. Then I commit.

Is there any major advantage to using `svn mv` when doing bulk moves like this, versus using a dual `svn cp` then `svn rm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they should be exactly the same. According to the SVN [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html):

```
This [mv] command is equivalent to an svn copy followed by svn delete
```

I'm surprised that the copy+delete is faster, but if it is, go for it.